# Google Vignette (Random Advertisement) Interrupt Test Flow

Tags: java, selenide

I had several **Selenide** automated test web sites which have Google Vignette. The google vignette have different iframe id. I cannot close it using automation code due to different google vignette button and different iframe id.

[image]

Questions:
How to deal with this kind of situation?

Any others solution?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with adblock extension but still not able to block it.

Comment: Please help me. Anyone has solution to it??

Answer (score 0):

You can walk down the DOM tree searching for the first element with the [blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur) styling, or another similar CSS attribute. To bar false positives, you can also filter by size. Then once you can locate the blurred vignette, there should be a fixed path on the tree from the vignette to the close button.

Comment: How to walk throught the blur() styling?

Comment: How to walk throught the blur() styling?